# Pagination with "cursors" using Admin-on-rest

Tags: pagination, admin-on-rest

My back-end API supports cursor based pagination for the GET_LIST operations.

```
API: {apiUrl}/{resource}?fltr={limit:100}

Response: 
{
data: [],
next: {reference_url_to_the_next_paginated_data_set}
}
```

What is the best way to supported this sort of pagination with the existing AOR pagination infrastructure ?

Comment: You ever got a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up achieving this using a Custom Saga, Action creator and Reducer.

1. Have a custom Saga take every GET_LIST_SUCCESS and dispatch a custom "UPDATE_PAGINATION" action for that resource.
2. Handle that action using a Custom Pagination Reducer. The reducer creates and maintains the "pagination" state for each resource, page-wise in the redux store
3. A Connected Pagination Component that is subscribed to the pagination state of that resource, that has a "next" and "previous" button and a "currentPage" state. On-Click  of "Next" or "Previous" buttons, fetch the "nextUrl" or the "previousUrl" for the "currentPage" and use AOR's fetch-meta to update the "data" state of that resource.
4. Use this custom Pagination component in your data-grid like so

```html
<List resource="myResource" pagination={<CustomPagination />} />
```

Comment: do you have a code example that you can share? How do you maintain the count and current offset

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a custom Rest client to handle your response and request type. You need your API to set the X-Total-Count header when your client makes a GET_LIST type request.

https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest/RestClients.html